# svn: Migrating repoA to repoB? Help!

Tags: svn, load, dump, svnadmin

I am trying to migrate from repoA containing the usual structure (branches, tags, and trunk) with subfolders in the trunk only to an existing RepoB that has projects and codes in branches, tags and trunk.

I have a dump file created through code:

```
svnadmin dump "s:\Repository_A" > x:\RepoA.svn_dump
```

This gives me everything from repoA.

Then I try to load RepoA.svn_dump to repoB using the following commend:

```
svnadmin load --parent-dir "svn://svn/_Backup" "S:\Repository_B" < X:\Ceto.svn_dump --ignore-uuid
```

It gives me an error message:

**Adding path: svn://svn/_backup/branches ...svnadmin: File not found: transaction 'xxxx=xxx', path 'svn://svn/_backup/branches'**

After googling, I added folders to RepoB using following commends:

```
svn mkdir -m "+ created branches in svn for repository backup.........." svn://svn/_Backup/trunk/Designs
svn mkdir -m "+ created branches in svn for repository backup.........." svn://svn/_Backup/trunk/Source
svn mkdir -m "+ created branches in svn for repository backup.........." svn://svn/_Backup/trunk/Tools
svn mkdir -m "+ created branches in svn for repository backup.........." svn://svn/_Backup/trunk/Videos
```

There is no subfolders in RepoA branches and tags and there are subfolders under the directories created above.

After this it still give me the same error

**Adding path: svn://svn/_backup/branches ...svnadmin: File not found: transaction 'xxxx=xxx', path 'svn://svn/_backup/branches'**

Where have I done wrong OR what should I actually do? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only add the parent parent dir:

```
svn mkdir -m "+ created parent-dir for repo import." svn://svn/_Backup/
```

btw: you could create multlple paths in a single transaction by adding more than 1 path in svn mkdir.

You must not include the protocol into your path:

```
svnadmin load --parent-dir "/_Backup" "S:\Repository_B" < X:\RepoA.svn_dump
```

Comment: Thanks so much Peter for the complete answer to reflect when I got it wrong and the tips for multiple paths when using svn mkdir.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try specifying the folder name for `--parent-dir` instead of `svn://`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Raghuram. I only realise your point completely when reading the answer from Peter. Sorry for being noob for this as I only started learning it lately.